# My Ubuntu showing Black Image on right corner

Tags: 23.04

how to remove the black image in the top right corner in Ubuntu 23.04?
i use wayland and my graphic Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

actually im confused, because i found wayland on my system wayland and also found X11 on folder X11

[X11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sPTa.png)
[wayland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peZy5.png)
[image: black image]

Comment: Please add to the question if you are running wayland or X11. Graphics card and driver?

Comment: updated, thankyou

Comment: HAve you tried X11?

Comment: actually im confused, because i found wayland on my system wayland and also found X11 on folder X11

Comment: Usually you can select X11/Wayland on the login screen, after you enter/select the username (gear symbol).